# Confusing byte array

Tags: java, byte, bit-fields

I have seen a proper byte array initialization as say

```
byte[] a = new byte[8];
```

But what does this mean?

```
byte[] bitfield = new byte [0xFFFFFFF/8];
n = 18;  // some integer
bitfield [n / 8] |= 1 << (n % 8);
```

Please also explain what does `0xFFFFFFF/8` means here.

Comment: Look up Java operators and hexadecimal representations.

Answer (score 2):

```
0xFFFFFFF/8
```

is simply a value(268435455) divided by 8, initializing the array to that size(truncated, of course).

At the next step we get `n` and set element `n/8`, or 2 due to truncation, to be that same element with a bitwise OR to `1<<(n%8)` or 1 shifted left `(n%8)` bits. This is equivalent of:

```
bitfield[n/8] = bitfield[n/8] | (1 << (n % 8))
```

Notice that `1<<(n%8)` is equal to `2^(n%8)` where `(n%8)` is the remainder when `n` is divided by 8.

Comment: `(rounded, of course).`. I would change this to `(truncated, of course)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, and without going into details, that construct is representing a bitset with a byte array which allows random access to the individual bits based on their position.

Answer (score 0):

`0xFFFFFFFF` is an integer literal in hexadecimal. Then it is divided by 8.